# record videos in avi with the Gnome’s built-in screen recorder

Tags: gnome

Is it possible to get the recorded videos in avi with the Gnome’s built-in screen recorder? Currently the videos are gotten in webm

Answer (score 0):

AVI is an old and rather primitive container format for video. It also cannot hold the modern, more efficient video codec Gnome use. Gnome’s built-in screen recorder does not support it, and likely will never support it.

If you really need the video without further editing in AVI format, you will need to transcode the original video. If, however, you edit the screen recording in a video-editor, then you can work directly with the files that the screenrecorder created and simply write out your edit as AVI with the appropriate video codec if there is a need.